# Angular modal window without bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-directive

I have searched and searched but cannot find any modal window directives for angular without relying on bootstrap. I managed to make leanModal.js working with it's own scope but it's not a great solution as there are a number of other problems occuring. My question is are there any angular modal directives without the use of bootstrap?

Comment: You can take the $modal service from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and swap default templates to make it work with any CSS framework.